# Python Pandas - largest change in population within the five year period

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:
[table_sensus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ0uG.jpg)

And I would like to retrieve which county has had the largest change in population within the five year period, how?

Thank you

Comment: Paste the data in the question instead of an image. That'll help others in reproducing and solving the problem.

Comment: the image doesn't support the description of data you gave..share a reproducible data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.argmax()` to get the biggest census and `.ix[]` to get the element by the index. After that you just have to select the column

```
>>> d = {'census' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),'county' : pd.Series(['z','x','w','y'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   census  county
a  1.0      z
b  2.0      x
c  3.0      w
d  NaN      y
>>> df.ix[df['census'].argmax()]['county']
'w'
```